# populate a List<Object1> based on another List<Object2> using java 8 stream

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

I have 2 `List` 
`List<Obligation>` and `List<ObligationStatus>`
Structure is as follows:

```
public class Obligation {
    private String topic;
    private String status;
    private String comment;
    private String text;
}
```

and

```
public class ObligationStatus {

    private String topic;
    private String status;
    private String comment;
}
```

**`status`** and **`comment`** inside `List<Obligation>` is **`null`** for all the elements,

`topic` is populated in both the `list`

I want to set the `status` and `comment` from each element of `List<ObligationStatus>` into each element of `List<Obligation>` based on `topic`.

```
        // this is what i have tried, and is working fine
        obList.stream().forEach(ob -> {
            osList.stream().forEach(os -> {
                if (ob.getTopic().equalsIgnoreCase(os.getTopic())) {
                    ob.setStatus(os.getStatus());
                    ob.setComment(os.getComment());
                }
            });
        });
```

```
// also tried to do this without using forEach, but compilation error here
        List<Obligation> result = obList.stream()
                .map(ob -> osList.stream().map(os -> os.getTopic().equals(ob.getTopic())).collect(Function.identity()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Can we do this without suing `forEach` ?

any info would be helpful.

Comment: Any reason why you want to avoid `forEach`?

Comment: @ernest_k No specific reason to avoid `forEach`. Curious to know and learn if there is another way to achieve it.

Comment: Maybe collect `obList` into a `Map<topic, obligation>` before running the other `forEach`. That will reduce the time complexity to O(n).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why use stream for this? Stream is not the right tool for mutating objects.

Use standard `for` loops. Makes code easier to understand too.

```
List<Obligation> obligationList = ...;
List<ObligationStatus> statusList = ...;

// For better performance, make a map
Map<String, ObligationStatus> statusMap = new HashMap<>(statusList.size());
for (ObligationStatus status : statusList)
    statusMap.put(status.getTopic(), status);

// Assign status values
for (Obligation obligation : obligationList) {
    ObligationStatus status = statusMap.get(obligation.getTopic());
    if (status != null) {
        ob.setStatus(status.getStatus());
        ob.setComment(status.getComment());
    }
}
```

If you want to do *some* stream logic, the first part is a good candidate:

```
// For better performance, make a map
Map<String, ObligationStatus> statusMap = statusList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(ObligationStatus::getTopic, Function.identity()));
```

---

**UPDATE**

Noticed that question code did `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` when comparing `topic` values. If that is really needed, change the `HashMap` to a case-insensitive `TreeMap`:

```
Map<String, ObligationStatus> statusMap = new TreeMap<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

The stream version of that gets convoluted, so better keep it old-style.

Comment: - `Why use stream for this? Stream is not the right tool for mutating objects.`
I thought stream is better approach. 
I am confused now.. which approach should I chose. standard `for` loop or stream?

Comment: @akapti Who said stream is better approach *for this*? Stream is not the right tool for *everything*. Sometimes a `for` loop is better. Sometimes a stream is better. Sometimes they are equally good.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are modifying an existing `List`, there's no need to use `collect`.

You could, however, use a single `forEach`. Locating the `ObligationStatus` instance matching the `Obligation` instance can be done with `filter` and `findFirst`.

```
obList.stream().forEach(ob -> {
    osList.stream()
          .filter(os -> ob.getTopic().equalsIgnoreCase(os.getTopic()))
          .findFirst()
          .ifPresent (os -> {
              ob.setStatus(os.getStatus());
              ob.setComment(os.getComment());
          });
});
```

Comment: Generally speaking, searching sequentially through `osList` is bad for performance. If the list is *known* to be small, it might be ok, but it's still bad for performance.